# How to start an Express server in best practice?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have an Express REST API server written in TypeScript.

At first, I started server like this -

```
const initServer = async() => {
  await connectDb();
  await server.listen(secrets.port, secrets.hostname, () => {
    logger.info(
          `Running server at http://${secrets.hostname}:${secrets.port} in ${
            secrets.env
          } env and API version is ${secrets.apiVersion}`
        );
  });
}
initServer().catch(error => logger.error(`Init server went wrong with: ${error}`));
```

Then I read a blog post suggesting to use `.then().catch()` -

```
async function initServer() {
  // Connect the database first
  await connectDb()
    .then(() =>
      // then start the server
      server.listen(secrets.port, secrets.hostname, () => {
        logger.info(
          `Running server at http://${secrets.hostname}:${secrets.port} in ${
            secrets.env
          } env and API version is ${secrets.apiVersion}`
        );
      })
    )
    .catch(err => {
      logger.error(`Initializing server went wrong with: ${err}`);
      process.exit(1);
    });
}
```

Then I read another blog post saying "catch the error first" -

```
async function initServer() {
  // Connect the database first
  await connectDb()
    // then start the server
    .then(() => server.listen(secrets.port, secrets.hostname))
    .catch(err => {
      logger.error(`Initializing server went wrong with: ${err}`);
      process.exit(1);
    })
    // then announce the server info
    .finally(() => {
      logger.info(
        `Running server at http://${secrets.hostname}:${secrets.port} in ${
          secrets.env
        } env and API version is ${secrets.apiVersion}`
      );
    });
}
```

But I feel like I'm not doing it right. Please educate me what I'm doing wrong.

How should I start the server?

Comment: `Finally` clause being run in any case (success or failure), IMHO I would follow your first snippet of code to start to log only when everything has started correctly.

Comment: @GaëlS Yes, that's exactly where I started confusing. I realized how `.finally()` behaves just last night. 

And still what if I replaced `.finally()` with `.then()` in the last snippet?

Comment: I think that could make it. I would still place the catch in last for readability though.